# Need help to identify manufacturer of this bathtub faucet

Tags: faucet, bathtub, cartridge

I have a bathtub faucet with a hand-hold shower head (2 handles, four holes) in my master BR (believe installed in 2008). The brand name inscription on the back of the sprout is "SENRY 5769 SH-47E". The associated logo is a maple leaf with a star. I need to identify the manufacture company for parts in order to fix the leaking divert cartridge.

Any help or guess is appreciated!

[image: Logo and brand name]
[image: divert cartridge]

Answer (score 0):

Having a name and an (implied but obvious) country should be more than enough to say that it might be [this company](https://www.canpages.ca/page/ON/windsor/senry-corporation/6085212) that does not show any signs of still existing.  There's a phone number in that link.  You may want to start contemplating a new faucet set or crafting your own washers.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jay!

Comment: I think you are right, Senry Corporation appears not existing any more. The phone is not working and no website.  I do think about making my own washer. The washer appears been constructed very uniquely without any screw or any obvious way to remove it from the stem. Any thoughts on how to remove the washer and craft a new one in general?

Comment: You need to figure out how it's held on.   The shiny knob has to come off somehow.  Then maybe the shaft is screwed down and comes apart in pieces.  Or maybe the washer is just forced on, and you have to pry it up.   It looks like the "business" end of the washer is the wedge-shaped part.  You'll need to find one of similar shape, with a hole that is the same or smaller.  You'll be able to expand a smaller hole to fit the shaft tightly.  I don't know of any DIY way to craft a clean angled face like that.

Comment: You can get an assortment of "cone washers" on Amazon for cheap.  I'd buy a bag of assorted sizes and try to force something into working.   Like I said, plan on a new faucet set at some point.

Comment: Got it! I will give it a try but also plan to get Moen T944BN if failed on washer (most likely). Thanks again Jay!